# When analyzing the worst case time complexity of search algorithms using Big O notation, why is the variable representing the input nonexistent?

Tags: time-complexity

Thanks for your willingness to help.

Straight to the point, I'm confused with the use of Big O notation when analyzing the worst case time complexity of search algorithms. 
For example, the worst case time complexity of Alpha-Beta Pruning is O(b^d) where ^ means ~ to the power of ~, b representing the average branching factor and d representing the depth of the search tree.

I do get that the worst case time complexity would be less or equal to a positive constant multiplied by b^d, but why is the use of big O notation permitted here? Where did the variable n, the input size, go? I do know that the input of same size might cause significant difference in time complexity of an algorithm.

All of the research I've done only explains "the use of big o notation in the analysis of worst case time complexity" in terms of the growth function, a function that has variable y as time complexity and variable x as input size. There are also formal definitions of big o notation, which make me even more confused with the question above. [definition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNUeE.png)[definition 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qBh8.png)

Any attempts to answer my question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input size you refer here to n is in this case d. If n is the amount of entries in your tree, d can be calculated by ln_2(n), assuming your tree is a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't really get what you mean by "n is the amount of entries in your tree"......Also, I'm sorry that I can't change the publicly displayed post score of your answer since my reputation is 1 (haha...).

Comment: When speaking about trees n refers to the amount of nodes in a tree, d usually to the depth. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation implies that you are discussing what the runtime would be for a very large n. In the case you noted, `O(b^d)`, the `n` is the variable that changes with input size. In this case, `d` would be your `n`. As you've found, some notations make use of many variables.

`n` is just a general term for the number of elements, but runtime could vary on many factors- depth of a tree, or a different list entirely. For example, to traverse lists like this:

```
for n in firstList:
    for k in secondList:
        do stuff
```

the cost would be `O(n*k)`.

Comment: Even though my confusion is already resolved by the answer above, I like your clear explanation. It assures me that I'd understood it properly. Thanks!